# Как передвинуть правый блок Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите знающие люди, необходимо передвинуть третий блок под первый. Так чтобы из трех коленчатого макета получился двух (При сужение экрана меньше 1200px)

[image: Так выглядит на больших мониторах]

И при уменьшение необходимо чтоб правый блок прыгал под левый.
[image: Так выглядеть должно при расширение меньше 1200 px]

Есть пример верхнего кода

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- main container -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well well-lg clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="alert alert-info">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /main container -->
</div>
```

Живой пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dmetelskis/ngsx3q7y/)

Answer (score 0):

Чисто бутстрапом не сделать. Перепиши код на дисплей flex. или через абсолют. Только при ресайзе. Иначе никак. Не так давно читал, что 4-й бутстрап уже будет иметь возможность фиксить такие проблемы.